# Netsuite: Hiding Line Items on Print

Tags: netsuite

I need to find out if there is a way to hide certain line items when a user hits the "Print" button on a transaction (quote, sales order, or Invoice). I am open to form manipulation or any variation in suitescript. I am not aware of any way to do this right now. Specific examples would be great. Pseducode for what I want to do is below:

```
function foo(){
  if (print == true){
  var itemCount = nlapiGetLineItemCount();
  for(var i = 1; i<= itemCount;i++){
     var itemID = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','item','i');
     if itemID is In list of ids to hide....
        ​hide Line Item;
   }   

  }
 }
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am trying to accomplish the same task.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1 :**

Create a saved search: Create a saved search with appropriate criteria to show the list of selected items under a sales order form.

**Step 2 :**

Customize the form: We need to customize the sales order form by clicking on the customize button under Setup -> Customization -> Transaction Forms.

**Step 3 :**

Once the form has been customized to meet your needs please select a saved search under the item filter. [image]

For more info please check out this [link](http://www.exploreconsulting.com/netsuite_tips_and_tricks.htm#netsuite_tip_75). Hope it will be helpful. :)

Comment: Unfortunately that won't quite work. I still want the items to be added to the actual transaction, just not printed for the transaction. What you are suggesting would limit the choice of items to be selected on the transaction as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same thing. This solution works ok: [link](https://www.mibar.net/blog/dynamically-print-items-on-a-netsuite-sales-order-using-advanced-pdf-templates/). It requires the use of advanced html/pdf templates, with all the conditional logic embedded in the template source code. You could also skip the step of creating a custom field if the existing fields contain consistent enough data to determine whether to add the line or not.